# Order model by association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Event model which has many EventDates.

An EventDate has a `start_time` attribute and an Event has a `next_occurrence` method which finds the EventDate belonging to it with the nearest `start_time`.

I want to find the first 5 Events ordered by `next_occurrence` (soonest first).

I thought I might be able to achieve that with something like this:

```
Event.joins(:event_dates).order('event_dates.start_time').limit(5)
```

but this isn't right - if I then collect the `next_occurrence` dates, they are out of order.

How could I query this to return Events ordered by `next_occurrence`?

Comment: soonest in the sense which has nearest `start_time` to that even date?

Comment: soonest as in the Events with the nearest **first** `start_time` of their EventDates.

Comment: ...I thought this would be easy. Maybe not?

Comment: In what way are they out of order?

Comment: post your `next_occurrence` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
next_5_events = EventDate.select('event_id, min(date) as next_event_date')
                         .includes(:event)
                         .where('next_event_date > ?', Time.now)
                         .group(:event_id)
                         .order(:next_event_date)
                         .limit(5)
                         .map(&:event)
```

**Explanation:**

Find for each `Event` the nearest `EventDate` in the future

```
EventDate.select('event_id, min(date) as next_event_date')
         .where('next_event_date > ?', Time.now)
         .group(:event_id)
```

Keep only the 5 first events ordered by the `next_event_date`

```
         .order(:next_event_date)
         .limit(5)
```

As is, the request would return only the `event_id` and the `next_event_date`, so the following lines eager load and return the `Event` objects

```
         .includes(:event)
         .map(&:event)
```

Comment: This is helpful for understanding how to approach this but I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'event' for main:Object`. If I remove the map method I get `Unknown column 'next_event_date'`

Comment: @benjaminjosephw There was a typo: it's `&:event` instead of `&event` . I fixed it. `map(&:event)` is a synomym of `map({|o| o.event})`

Comment: Oh yes, I should have spotted that! Thanks. Still getting this though: `Unknown column 'next_event_date' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @benjaminjosephw Can you try with `where('min(date) > ?', Time.now)` instead ? and maybe also `.order('min(date) ASC')`

Comment: Still not quite there (getting `Mysql2::Error: Invalid use of group function: SELECT  event_id, min(start_time) as next_event_date FROM 'event_dates'  WHERE (min(start_time) > '2014-05-09 18:25:12') GROUP BY event_id  ORDER BY 'event_dates'.'next_event_date' ASC LIMIT 5`) but I've got a better idea of what I'm aiming at.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't try this out, but I think it works.  It finds the upcoming events in a subquery, then gives you the first 5.

```
Event.joins("(
  select event_dates.event_id, max(start_time)
  from event_dates
  group by event_dates.event_id
  order by max(start_time) desc
) as upcoming_events on events.id = upcoming_events.event_id")
.limit(5)
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an SQL syntax error which I can't work out (I'm not an SQL pro).